# Anyone know a way to find out the number of Twitter followers for a particular account on any given date?

Tags: statistics, twitter

I manage two corporate Twitter accounts and two personal Twitter accounts, and it would be really useful to know how many followers each account has at the end of each week.

I'm using TweetStats.com to gather statistics at the moment, but the follower stats functionality isn't granular enough to determine the precise number of followers.

Does anyone know of any useful and free tools that can provide the exact number of followers for a specific Twitter account on any given date?

Comment: Mike - this question does not appear to relate to [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). If you want to know how to get this information using the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids), your question would be a better fit for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=twitter+followers).

Comment: @danlefree, that's an interesting observation because many of the questions on Webmasters actually relate to Search Marketing (especially SEO and Google Analytics). Maybe it would be worth expanding the scope to make Webmasters the forum to use for these types of question? I know that using the twitter API is a programming topic, but most people's reason to use the twitter API is to gain marketing intelligence. I'm just speculating because I find the current scope of Webmaster a bit limited with too many similar questions.

Comment: @EwanHeming - well worth discussion, but please switch the venue to [meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://twittercounter.com/

Comment: This is *exactly* what I need, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Note that there may be some limitations on how much data you can get for free, they have paid accounts with more features. There is a large amount of public data available for free, though, and additionally info for your own account(s) if you sign up with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many people are actually influenced by your twitter account, as opposed to how many people read your tweets, you can tweet a link using goo.gl.

goo.gl allows you to see how many people clicked on a link, which is a useful trick to see a rough underestimate of how many people you are reaching and really have an interest in what you are tweeting.